# DFS slowly and using a lot write speed on sender member

Tags: active-directory, performance

I am transferring 400gb of multiple files trough 2 server whit 10gb connection inside one VLAN. When I had 2 servers that were not in production the transfer was very quick using 100% of 1gb connection. But now I am transferring one production server whit hard disc 100% Active Time(24hrs) because the dfs is using alot of write speed one raid 10 server plus multiple users using this streaming server. I spent 24 hours to transfer just 40gb, the staging quota(400gb), RDC(Disabled). Can I do another step to do this faster? I dont need any backup data, just transfer asap. Why DFS is using writing speed on SENDER MEMBER? The connection does not reach more than 5% of use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard disk on your production server cannot **read and write** information from several random places at the same time. It have more than one head, but the number of simultaneous IO operations is limited.

Because of this, if your server is writing lots of data, the read speed will be impacted. This penalty would be negligible if the server have SSD disks, but with HDD this will happen.

You can test this on any computer: copy 1000 files from one folder to another in only one copy operation and write down the time it needed. Then erase the files and copy again, but in 5-10 simultaneous copy operations. Even if you copied the exact same files, the time will be higher on the second operation because the disk will have to move the write read back and forth lots of times because of the simultaneous operations.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but I'm nervous if I just copy one file via ftp this can be very faster(50x), the dfs is creating background workers writting things I dont need, If I copy and paste a file on same server, it will use read/write, but if I just use read way to paste on another server, this server can handle easily 300 mb/s. At moment I will test one simple ftp.

Comment: @LucasRodriguesSena Why do you say not need= DFS does exactly what it was configured to do - assuming it is DFS it is starting a replication in the background. You do not like it? Well, remove it.

Comment: I will do one ftp just one time, and DFS for keep theses folders SYNC, 24 hrs full bandwidth. I think it is the best way. Use one simple ftp for large files size, and keep DFS working on that right? Or another suggest?

Comment: @ThoriumBR, I detected the delay when creating staging files.